# Camel unit tests setting expectations on mock component

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, apache-camel

I am writing unit test cases using camel-test following steps outlined [here](http://camel.apache.org/mock.html). Under section **Mocking existing endpoints using the camel-test component**, there is a snippet

```
    getMockEndpoint("mock:direct:start").expectedBodiesReceived("Hello World");
    getMockEndpoint("mock:direct:foo").expectedBodiesReceived("Hello World");
    getMockEndpoint("mock:log:foo").expectedBodiesReceived("Bye World");
    getMockEndpoint("mock:result").expectedBodiesReceived("Bye World");

    template.sendBody("direct:start", "Hello World");

    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
```

I want to do something similar but my body type is a POJO without an overridden `equals` method.

I tried

```
getMockEndpoint("mock:result").message(0).method(new Object() {
    public boolean deepEquals(Exchange in) {
    MyPojo pojo = in.getIn().getBody(MyPojo.class); 

    return //custom pojo equals logic;
    }

}, "deepEquals").isEqualTo(true);
```

but am getting

```
Assertion error at index 0 on mock mock://result with predicate: BeanExpression[ method: deepEquals] == true evaluated as: null == true on Exchange[Message: MyPojo...]
```

The contents of the message is exactly as a I want however the test fails. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you have a copy of the Camel in Action book, read chapter 6, section 6.2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
final MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");
    mock.expects(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            MyPojo myPojo = mock.getExchanges().get(0).getIn().getBody(MyPojo.class);
            boolean status = //custom pojo equals logic;
            if(!status){
                fail("Testcase fails");
            }
        }
    });
```

and another way,

```
mock.whenAnyExchangeReceived(new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

            MyPojo myPojo = exchange.getIn().getBody(MyPojo.class);
            boolean status =//custom pojo equals logic;

            exchange.getIn().setBody(status);
        }
    });
    boolean out = template.requestBody(url, new MyPojo(), Boolean.class);
    assertEquals(true, out);
```

Comment: thanks works like a charm, i used the first one as I like the style of setting up expectations beforehand in a test case. But isnt this too much code just for a simple use case ? And since our check is being done inside a Runnable is it guaranteed that it AssertionError thrown there will break our test ?

Answer (score 0):

Weird. I am getting the same error. There seems to be a bug in the reflection code where the bean expression is evaluated, probably due to this being an anonymous inner class.

Try this instead:

```
getMockEndpoint("mock:result").message(0).method(new Foo(), "deepEquals").isEqualTo(true);
```

And move the `deepEquals` method to named class `public static class Foo` in your test class somewhere.

Comment: Weird. When I moved it to `public static class Foo` the error disappeared. Camel 12.3